# Table A results based on distance to point in table B

Tags: postgis

I have 2 tables, locations and zipcodes.

Both the locations and zipcodes tables have a single point geometry.

I wrote a query that I can pass string values for lng,lat to, but I'd like to the same thing by only passing in a zipcode, which is what the distance results would be based off of.

```
SELECT *, ST_distance(geometry::geography, ST_PointFromText('POINT(-118.0754445 32.4836479)', 4326)::geography) as dist 
  FROM locations
  WHERE st_dwithin(geometry, ST_PointFromText('POINT(-118.0754445 32.4836479)', 4326)::geography, 1609)
  ORDER BY dist;
```

Answer (score 0):

Put both tables in the FROM clause (assign them a alias) and add a where condition with the zipcode you need:

```
SELECT *, ST_distance(l.geometry::geography, zc.geometry::geography ) as dist 
  FROM locations AS l, zipcodes AS zc
  WHERE st_dwithin(l.geometry, zc.geometry::geography), 1609) AND
        zc.code = 11111
  ORDER BY dist;
```